# Outlook Visual Studio Built Add-in location?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, add-in, visual-studio-2013

I've developed a Microsoft Outlook Add-in using Visual Studio 2013.
Currently it only displays in the top bar when an email is double clicked to open.
I'm trying to figure out how to set it so that the Add-in is also available on the main level.

So you could simply click once on the email to view it as you usually would (highlighting the email) and then click the button function in the add-in directly from that main outlook window. Without having to double click and open the email to view the add-in and click it's function button.

Not sure which part of the code to include for this...

Thanks.

Comment: Using the Visual Designer Ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

How do you return the ribbon XML? Your implementation of IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI must return the appropriate XML when the RibbonID parameter is "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer"

Comment: It's coded in c# - VS 2013
The only mention of XML is
"using System.Xml.Linq;"

Comment: I'm using the Visual Designer Ribbon not the XML.

Comment: I do not use it, but have you seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398246.aspx ?

Comment: Sadly that did not assist me.
Does anyone know where to add the custom ui code or where to change it if it's already present, or what code is actually necessary to simply place a fully built and functional add-in on the main bar instead of only being available after opening an email.

Comment: In the url above, did you read about the RibbonType property? What did you set it to in your addin?